# How to show regexp

Tags: linux, bash, regex

I want to show what stands behind a regexp, for example, I want to print all chars covered by **[A-z]** in the bash.

Comment: Do you realize that a regexp generally doesn't identify a single string? Actually this is the whole point of regexsps. I'm just trying to explain why I don't understand your question.

Comment: The regex mentioned above are'nt equals [A-Za-z] but some more Characters, and I want to know them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in Python.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('[A-z]')
for ch in range(1,255):
        if (pattern.match(chr(ch))):
                print chr(ch),
```

Save it to a file and execute it as `python your_filename`. It tests every single-byte character against your regular expression and prints it out if it matches.